# Unstyled component at first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Im having unstyled mui and antd components at first render, what can be the problem? Here this is my webpack dev file. Im  using webpack 5 and thread loader.And use styled components for injection of CSS into components. I really considered this problem and make some assumptions but couldn't go anywhere..

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const ProgressBarPlugin = require("progress-bar-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const fs = require("fs");
const lessToJs = require("less-vars-to-js");
var CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require("case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin");
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const numOfCpus = require("os").cpus().length;
const outputPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "docs/assets");
const devServerRootPath = path.join(__dirname, "docs");
const publicPath = "/assets/";
const nodeModulesDir = path.join(__dirname, "node_modules");
const indexFile = path.join(__dirname, "src/index.js");
const themeVars = path.join(__dirname, "src/style/antd-theme-overrides.less");
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

const threadLoader = require("thread-loader");

const jsWorkerPool = {
  poolTimeout: 4000,
  workers: numOfCpus - 1,
  workerParallelJobs: 400,
};
threadLoader.warmup({ jsWorkerPool }, [
  "thread-loader",
  "babel-loader",
  "css-loader",
  "sass-loader",
  "less-loader",
]);

// specific antd:
const themeVariables = lessToJs(fs.readFileSync(themeVars, "utf8"));
/* eslint-disable quotes */
// lessToJs does not support @icon-url: "some-string", so we are manually adding it to the produced themeVariables js object here
// themeVariables['@icon-url'] = "'//localhost:3000/src/style/fonts/antd-fonts/iconfont'";
/* eslint-enable quotes */
// #endregion

const config = {
  mode: "development",
  //cheap-module-source-map
  devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",
  entry: {
    app: indexFile,
  },
/*   externalsPresets: { node: false }, // in order to ignore built-in modules like path, fs, etc.
  externals: [nodeExternals()], // in order to ignore all modules in node_modules folder
 */
  resolve: {
    modules: ["src", "node_modules"],
    alias: {
      components: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components/"),
    },
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  stats: { warnings: false },
  output: {
    path: outputPath,
    publicPath,
    filename: "[name].js",
    clean: true,
    chunkFilename: "chunks/[name]-[chunkhash].js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "thread-loader",
            options: jsWorkerPool,
          },
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
        ],
      },
      
      {
        test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "thread-loader",
            options: jsWorkerPool,
          },
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/,
        exclude: [nodeModulesDir],
        use: [
          {
            loader: "thread-loader",
            options: jsWorkerPool,
          },
          "babel-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpe?g|gif)(\?\S*)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "thread-loader",
            options: jsWorkerPool,
          },

          {
            loader: "url-loader",
            options: {
              limit: 100000,
              name: "[name].[ext]",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "thread-loader",
            options: jsWorkerPool,
          },
          "style-loader",
          { loader: "css-loader", options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
          "sass-loader",

          {
            loader: "less-loader",
            options: { javascriptEnabled: true, modifyVars: themeVariables },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  watch: true,

  performance: {
    hints: "warning",
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: "../index.html",
      template: "src/statics/index.html",
    }),
    new ProgressBarPlugin({
      format: "ESBİS Yükleniyor [:bar] :percent (:elapsed seconds)",
      clear: false,
    }),
    new NodePolyfillPlugin(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      Promise: "bluebird",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      $: "jquery",
      React: "react",
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    //webpack 4
    compress: true,
    static: path.resolve(__dirname, "docs"),
    port: 8001,
    hot: false,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    client: {
      overlay: {
        errors: false,
        warnings: false,
      },
      
      progress: true,
    },
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the thread-loader to load your CSS files. This loader will load each CSS file in a separate thread, which can improve performance. However, it can also cause problems with components that use CSS.

The problem is that when a component uses CSS, it needs to be able to access the CSS variables that are defined in the CSS file. However, when the CSS file is loaded in a separate thread, the component may not be able to access the CSS variables until the thread has finished loading.

To fix this problem, you can use the style-loader instead of the thread-loader. The style-loader will load the CSS files in the main thread, which will ensure that the components can access the CSS variables immediately.

To do this, change the following line in your webpack configuration:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: "thread-loader",
      options: jsWorkerPool,
    },
    "style-loader",
    "css-loader",
  ],
},
```

to

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    "style-loader",
    "css-loader",
  ],
},
```

This should fix the problem with your components not being styled on the first render.

Comment: hello, didnt work but thank you